# Why doesn't this SQL code work using a simple predicate in a WHERE EXISTS construction?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a sample database to learn SQL as part of a class. One task was "List names of employees who are managers using EXISTS". (I already completed the assignment, so it is okay to get an answer here).

I originally used this:

```
SELECT `FIRSTNAME`
     , `MIDINIT`
     , `LASTNAME` 
  FROM `emp` 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `emp` WHERE `JOB`='MANAGER')
```

However, it simply would not work.

It kept showing the names of ALL employees in the `emp` table instead of the 7 where `JOB`='MANAGER'.

Here is the weird part.

When I just run

```
(SELECT * FROM `emp` WHERE `JOB`='MANAGER')
```

it works to show just the 7 rows where employees are managers.
[results showing just the rows where JOB = 'MANAGER'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqd6a.png)

So, why doesn't it work as the WHERE EXISTS predicate?

In order to get it to work, I had to do this:
SELECT `FIRSTNAME`, `MIDINIT`, `LASTNAME` FROM `emp` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `dept` WHERE `emp`.`EMPNO`=`dept`.`MGRNUMBER`)
I had to compare EMPNO in the `emp` table with MGRNUMBER in the `dept` table. I do not understand why I had to go to another table to compare values.

Comment: `EXISTS` need a correlated subquery to make sense. As it is now, you will either get all rows (if a row WHERE `JOB`='MANAGER' exists), or no rows at all (if such row doesn't exist.)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what was happening--I was getting all rows. I thought that it would gather all the information from the subquery and then run the main query on the subquery. It does not work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query:

```
SELECT `FIRSTNAME`
     , `MIDINIT`
     , `LASTNAME` 
  FROM `emp` 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `emp` WHERE `JOB`='MANAGER')
```

...works like this. For each row found in the table, it checks the WHERE clause, which looks for the existence of any rows with Job = 'MANAGER'. It finds some, so it includes the row. Then it gets the next row and repeats the same check (which passes) so it includes the next row. It repeats for each row and so includes all the rows in the table.

@GenYMaverick's answer is one way to use an EXISTS, but I wouldn't use it in production. I'd use the query you came up with, because it's the simplest, most natural, and probably the most efficient way to do it. (I would also hope that the query optimiser was good enough to reduce @GenYMaverick's query to yours; they're logically te same.)

Answer (score 1):

This query should solve your problem:

You don't need to access another table.

The EXISTS operate is an operator which is testing whether something exists in the sub query or not. It returns TRUE if there is a match.

So if you only want to use the emp table then you have to connect the queries within the sub query by using EMPNO.

In my example I did this by declaring the table emp in the main query as emp1 and in the sub query as emp2. This makes it possible search for the existence of the EMPNO in the sub query.

```
SELECT 
     FIRSTNAME,
     MIDINIT,
     LASTNAME 
FROM emp emp1 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
               FROM emp emp2 
               WHERE emp1.EMPNO = emp2.EMPNO 
                 AND emp2.JOB='MANAGER' );
```

Comment: I am new enough at SQL that I don't understand the emp1 or emp2 here. I guess that would be making new tables that are copies of the original table?

Comment: @mdign002 *I don't understand the emp1 or emp2* These are aliases. Temporary, per-this-query, table copies names for to distinguish what table's column is used in each expression. Needed in the condition ```WHERE emp1.EMPNO = emp2.EMPNO```